# Equal height for all li elements under UL

Tags: jquery, css

Anyone know about how we can use equal height for all `<li>` elements under a `<ul>` element?

Comment: Check the last example in the API for `map()`: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: What have *you* tried? Show us you put in some effort, and the community will answer your question gladly.

Comment: Since you haven't posted anything in terms of what you've tried, this question shows little (no) research effort.

Comment: set a height on the list items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Please see the JS code below, which makes it possible to apply equal height to all `<li>` elements:

```
setHeight($('.media-listing > ul > li'));

function setHeight(col) {
    var $col = $(col);

    var $maxHeight = 0;
    $col.each(function () {
        var $thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        if ($thisHeight > $maxHeight) {
            $maxHeight = $thisHeight;
        }
    });
    $col.height($maxHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything complicated...you can do this through pure styling!

CSS:

li{

```
height: 100px; //you can also use percentages - 100%
max-height: 100px; //just to make sure
min-height: 100px; //just to make sure
```

}

If they are not equal after doing that then something else, either another style or some javascript is influencing it.  Don't just correct one mistake by making another, that way your code will degrade fast.  Search for the external influence and correct it the right way.